# How can I compare the value of two predicates prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I have three predicates that return half the number of elements
 in a list, the number of ones and the number of zeros.

I need to write a predicate that returns false if half the number of elements is smaller than the numbers of zeros on a list and returns false if half the number of elements is smaller than the numbers of ones on a list

this is what i did, but it's not working:

```
   apply(L,R):- number_elements(L,0) < number_zeros(L,0),!,fail.
   apply(L,R):- number_elements(L,0) < number_ones(L,0),!,fail.
```

My number_elements is:

```
number_elements(List, HalfCount) :- length(List, N), HalfCount is N div 2.
```

My number_ones is equal to my number_zeros:

```
number_ones([], 0).
number_ones([H|T], N) :-
   number_ones(T, X),
   (  H == 1
   -> N is X+1
   ;  N is X
   ).
```

Thanks!

Comment: *Predicates* in Prolog are not *functions*. They do not return values. So `number_elements(L,0)` does not return a value. A *predicate* only succeeds or fails (or doesn't terminate if it has a problem). What's the purpose of the `0` argument in your calls to `number_elements`, `number_zeros` and `number_ones`?

Comment: already did, sorry thank you so much for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

In Prolog, your predicates cannot return values other than `true`/`false`, so you cannot write queries such as `predicate1 < predicate2`. If you want to "return a number", you encode it in the variables of your predicates. You wrote you already have the predicates `number_elements` and `number_zeros` / `number_ones` defined. I assume that these predicates are "returning" the number via their second variable, such that e.g.

```
?- number_zeros([0,1,2], 0).
false.
?- number_zeros([0,1,2], 1).
true .
?- number_zeros([0,1,2], N).
N = 1 .
```

The comparison you wanted can now be written by calling your predicates with variables for their second arguments and then comparing these variables:

```
apply(L) :-
  length(L, N),
  number_zeros(L, M0),
  number_ones(L, M1),
  H is N//2,
  H >= M0,
  H >= M1.
```

Comment: The number_zeros "return" the number of zeros that is in the list not via their second variable, I add the predicate so you can see

Comment: The definitions of `number_zeros` / `number_ones` you added do use the second variable to encode the number of zeros/ones. What other purpose would the second variable have in your understanding?